# Simple switch with TLP222A

Tags: switches, optoelectronics

Electronic newbie here.

I'm trying to use a [TLP222A](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=17036&prodName=TLP222A-2) as a remote switch for a small signal (3V and about 150-200mA at most).

It's super simple, but I can't understand why the following happens:

I'm powering the TLP222A connecting pin 1 and pin 2 (anode and catode) directly to a power supply that provides 5V and 40mA, connecting and disconnecting the anode with a momentary switch.

First, I have tried to turn on and off a led connecting it to the same 5V and ground through the TLP222A and it works perfectly. The led turns on when I connect pin 2(anode) to 5V and it turns off when I disconnect it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frpOrR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(D1, D2, D3, M1 and M2 are part of the TLP222A)

Then, I have tried to connect two cables to pin 3 and pin 4 to check if I have conductivity when pin 1 and 2 are connected to the power supply. The tester never indicates conductivity.

I have also tried to connect the cables to the device that I want to control remotely and nothing happens.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUpupf.png)</sup>

Could someone help me to understand what is wrong in my approach?

Thanks

Comment: What the heck is a TLP222A? Can you provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet? Also, please use the built-in schematic editor to draw a schematic of your circuit.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I stack exchange has a built-in schematic editor. I've added the schematic for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be connecting the LED of the TLP222A directly across a 5 V power supply. It's only rated for 50 mA continuous, and it only worked the first time because the power supply went into current limiting. Always use a series resistor.

I suspect that you've blown the diode, which is why it has stopped working.

Comment: I'm powering the TLP222A with 5V and 40mA, so it's under the limit. I have been able to reproduce the same test without problems multiple times.. I don't think the diode is blown yet

Answer (score 0):

Continuity Tests should not be performed on a powered circuit. You will, most likely, get misleading results and, at worst, end up with a busted continuity meter.

Also, you probably already realize this but the power and ground associated with pins 1 and 2, should be physically isolated from the power and ground associated with pins 3 and 4, or you're not getting much utility out of an optical-isolator.

[image]

Note you need a current limiting resistor, to limit the current in the path through pins 1 and 2 (which are the internal LED) to about 50mA, as per the test circuit in the datasheet (and the absolute maximum ratings table):

[image]

I'm pretty sure pins 3 and 4 are symmetric, but one of them should be connected to your load-side ground.

Answer (score 0):

The results you get will depend on how your tester performs its test for continuity, and how it defines "continuity". The datasheet says that the "on" resistance is 2Ω. Perhaps that's too high for the tester to deem it a "short circuit".

I'm guessing, but the two transistors in the opto-isolator may require some minimum voltage across them to achieve that on-state resistance. If the tester doesn't provide the right conditions, then there's no guarantee that the path through those transistors is actually 2Ω.